# Rails , Model created inside a namespace cannot be accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have created a model named "RandomStuff" inside namespace "Module".. but when i try `Module::RandomStuff` in rails console. it gives the following error

> Module::RandomStuff(Table doesn't exist)

and cant access it anywhere in my rails app. when i run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` in irb the table "module_random_stuffs" is listed there..

Here are the steps i followed , Let me know if i am missing something

```
rails generate model Module::RandomStuff
```

then added one column in the migration file

```
    class CreateModuleRandomStuffs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :module_random_stuffs do |t|
      t.string :test_column
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and then ran the following command

```
rake db:migrate
```

Still i am unable to access the model any where..

Comment: In your Module::RandomStuff class do you have `self.table_name = 'module_random_stuffs'?`

Comment: Thanks alot @DVG.. u really made my day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @DVG for pointing it out.

The following line was missing in my model Modul::RandomStuff

```
  self.table_name = 'module_random_stuffs'
```

Answer (score 1):

### I just love these situations.

**Sometimes**, when Rails fails to load **something** it acts as if that **something** *never existed*. You can run into this issue if, for some reason, some constant (class or module at least, I've seen with both) had a mistake in its definition, but since it was optional, no error was thrown.

I actually ran into the same issue when using [`active_model_serializers`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). It tries to infer a serializer class from model's name. If it fails to find a matching one, it falls back to "serializerless" rendering. That confused me for a second, I was pretty sure I defined it, even in the proper file.

In your specific case Rails has to define a module called `Module` in order to specify a common table prefix there. Like so:

```
module Module
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'module_'
  end
end
```

But try defining a module `Module` in `irb` and **Ruby will refuse**:

```
module Module
end
# TypeError: Module is not a module
```

It's not a module? Huh. Then what is it?

```
Module.class
# => Class
```

A class? That's right, moreover, it's a [Ruby core class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html). So **just choose a different module name**. What you've chosen collides with something really essential.

#### Hacky mode (never actually do this, otherwise... [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat))

You can fix that by altering the generated `module.rb`, replacing `module` with `class`. That will reopen the `Module` class and define your model inside it, making things work as expected. But technically, this is an absolutely unnecessary monkeypatch.